# Is my counter variable safe for concurrent tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Is below counter thread safe? I think that if I reach the sync function over async function, counter would work fine. Am I right? My explanation is function a() is sync function. It means that this function is atomic, that's why only one process works inside. it also means that counter get increased safely ?

```
    `var counter = 0;
     function a(){
     counter++
     }
     async function count(){
      //IO code;
      a();
     } 
     count();`
```

Comment: if I had reached the counter variable directly from async function, would counter variable be safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code is thread safe. Most values (except SharedArrayBuffers) can't be shared between threads, so they can't be accessed concurrently by two different threads.

As you mentioned "async functions": They run asynchronously in the sense that they might halt at specified points (basically when you `await`), and other code might run then, but all the other code will run till completion (so other code might only run inbetween when you use `await`).

An example of the same operation that could fail:

```
  counter = counter + await Promise.resolve(1);
```

This might fail as `counter` gets evaluated, then the promise gets `await`ed, other code might change `counter` in the meantime, and then you assign back to `counter`.